# Which is faster, (n==0 or n==1) or (n*(n-1)==0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the first time for me to ask a question in this site. Recently, I was learning python 3.x and I got a question...

Which is faster ?

```py
if n==0 or n==1:
```

or

```py
if n*(n-1)==0:
```

Similarly, for a,b,c,d are numbers, which is faster?

```py
if n==a or n==b or n==c or n==d:
```

or

```py
if (n-a)*(n-b)*(n-c)*(n-d)==0:
```

I have been confused of this question for some time. I asked my friend but they didn't know too. Answer is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What did your benchmark tests say?

Comment: There is no benchmark tests actually, I thought of myself

Comment: You can easily write them yourself.

Comment: How to write then?

Comment: See the answer you got. But generally your question seems to be _off-topic_ here for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides of searching *"what is faster"* always consider code readability and maintainability.

Due to **`or`** operator nature, most of sub-checks could be just skipped on "earlier" match, whereas with the 2nd approach `(n-a)*(n-b)*(n-c)*(n-d)==0` whatever **`n`** value would be - the long sequence of arithmetic operations `(n-a)*(n-b)*(n-c)*(n-d)` will inevitably be performed, which obviously makes the 2nd approach less efficient. Moreover it looks more confusing in case of simple comparisons.

As for time performance, consider the following tests:

```
In [121]: a,b,c,d = range(1,5)                                                                                               

In [122]: n=4                                                                                                                

In [123]: %timeit n==a or n==b or n==c or n==d                                                                               
176 ns ± 8.52 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [124]: %timeit (n-a)*(n-b)*(n-c)*(n-d)==0                                                                                 
213 ns ± 6.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [125]: n=2                                                                                                                

In [126]: %timeit n==a or n==b or n==c or n==d                                                                               
108 ns ± 1.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [127]: %timeit (n-a)*(n-b)*(n-c)*(n-d)==0                                                                                 
241 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module can help you to measure the speed of the statements:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('n == 0 or n == 1', 'n = 42')
0.045291900634765625
>>> timeit.timeit('n * (n-1) == 0', 'n = 42')
0.0594179630279541
```

The first one is faster on `python 2.7.15`, but what is much more important is that it is less obscure and more maintainable.

Comment: Please refrain from answering off topic questions